# Как переопределить класс из дочерней темы?

Tags: php, wordpress

В теме вордпресс используется встроенный плагин, т.е. при установке темы нужно ещё в папку с плагинами установить этот дополнительный плагин к теме, расширяющий возможности, без плагина тема не будет работать.
И в этом плагине в корне лежит класс, без проверки на наличие класса: `if(!function_exists('Dfd_Theme_extensions')){`
т.е. нельзя переопределить класс из дочерней темы из-за отсутствия проверки `function_exists` в этом плагине, там сразу идёт определение класса.
и после класса его инициализация:

```
$Dfd_Theme_extensions = new Dfd_Theme_extensions();
```

Как можно переопределить этот класс?
Сам этот плагин весит 17 мб.

Comment: Его нельзя переопределить, можно только написать свой класс на основе этого. А зачем его переопределять? Возможно в классе есть какие-нибудь фильтры и хуки, тут без кода сложно сказать.

Comment: нет хуков в этом и других классах

Comment: тогда никак, вам нужно наследовать класс и уже вызывать экземпляр наследуемого класса.Если задачу ставить так,как вы написали. Есть еще [это](https://php.net/manual/en/function.runkit-method-add.php) но расширение runkit не рекомендуют использовать.

Comment: а в файле `functions.php` дочерней темы этот плагин ведь ещё не инициализирован, как от этого класса тогда можно наследовать другой класс?

Comment: в этом плагине может и есть хуки, но их слишком мало, в основном без них, странная конечно тема

Comment: вам нужно подключать класс в экшене `after_setup_theme` он должен срабатывать после инициализации род темы


`function mytheme_includes() {
 require_once get_theme_file_path( 'includes/class-my-class.php' );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'mytheme_includes' );`